# orangeHRM sendmail option Notworking

Tags: sendmail, orangehrm

I have configured orange HRM in live server,But issue with sendmail notworking
please suggest me what will the solution for this issue.

Comment: Can you tell me which type of configuration you done?

Comment: Linux Hosting configuration which i have done

Comment: Have you done any configuration in HRMS?

Comment: Yes i have configured